# Send function from one class to the other and execute it in C++

Tags: c++, class, function, inheritance, signature

I want to make a class, let's name it class A, that executes functions from other classes. So I want to inherit my classes from this A class and class A to be able to receive function addresses from the derived classes and execute them.

This is what I thought so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class A
{
public:
    // a typedef for the function I want to execute 
    // which has no parameters and void as return type
    typedef void (T::*SpecialFunc)();

    A() { }

    //this is the function that executes the received functions
    void exec(SpecialFunc func)
    {
        ((new T)->*func)();
    }
};

class B : public A<B>
{
public:
    B()
    {
        // call A::exec to call my function
        exec(&B::funcB);
    }

    //function I want to be executed
    void funcB()
    {
        cout << "testB\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    B ob;

    return 0;
}
```

What I want is function funcB to be called. So far my program breaks with no error, just heavily breaks. 
I know that this code can't work because I try to build class A that needs information from class B and class B needs information from the first class A to be constructed but I hope you understand better what I'm willing to achieve.

Can this be achieved?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using std::function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have infinite recursion here. You call `exec()` in constructor of `B`, it creates new `B` object by `new` statement which calls constructor of `B` which calls `exec()` etc. Probably you need to pass ponter or reference to `B` object to `exec()` to avoid its construction.

And of course `B` object leak in `exec()` doesn't look good. I hope it's just for testing purposes...

Comment: I moved line `exec(&B::funcB);` from constructor `B()` to a `void run()` function and called it using the object `ob` like this: `ob.run()`. Now code runs how I expect.

Regarding the object leak...how can I deallocate the memory of a temporary `new Type`?

Comment: You must use `delete` on it. Or **much better** use smart pointer, it will do the cleanup for you. `std::unique_ptr` if you use C++11, `std::auto_ptr` or `boost::scoped_ptr` if older C++03.

Comment: By the way why do you need `new` here? Object scope is local, so just create it on stack: `void exec(SpecialFunc func)  
{  
 T obj;  
 (obj.*func)();  
}`

Comment: thank for the answers :)
I also thought on using smart pointers or creating an object but I thought there is a possibility of freeing the memory allocated at `new Type` giving the fact that `new Thing` is a temporary object and has no name.

Answer (score 1):

1) "class A that needs information from class B and class B needs
information from the first class A"

-to prevent circular reference use **forward declaration**

2) I suggest the following **implemintation of you idea**:

1. *Abstract class* with *pure virtual function/s* (class Abstr)
2. Other classes inherit from it (derived)
3. Class manager - gets as argument abstract class, you can provide any derived class and calls virtual function for ceratain class

I think given approach will allow you to use OOP ideas more efficiently